# Can't change the default color and font size of labels in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

So I want to render a simple bar graph in my website, I am using react-chartjs-2 for the same but I can't seem to change the default fontsize or even the color of the x label and ylabels. I have gone through the other answers but none of them are working for me. I have been at it for the last 2 hours and I still can't figure out whats the problem.

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import './model.css'
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2'

function Model() {
    const data = {
        labels: ['red', 'blue', 'white', 'green'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '# of days',
            data: [6, 7, 2, 14],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
              
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      };
     const options= { 
        legend: {
            labels: {
                fontColor: "blue",
                fontSize: 18
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "white",
                    fontSize: 14,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
     

    return (
        <div className="model-container">
            
            <Bar
                data={data}
                options={options}   
            />
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would asume you are using v3, in v3 the scales have been reworked in how you write them, you can read all changed in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html), to know for sure where to put the options and how there name is you can just check the documentation itself

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'red',
          font: {
            size: 14,
          }
        }
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: 'red',
          font: {
            size: 14
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Nice code. Solve I problem that I had trying to size the label of a bar in `react chartjs`. Where did you find the docs for this to apply to `react chartjs` as there is nothing on the web.

Comment: React chartjs is just a reactive wrapper around the chart.js lib so you can use those docs as I linked to for the migration guide